# bash "command not found" error even though the command fires

Tags: bash, shell, variables, rsync

I'm building some small test files to start learning bash scripting.

One of the files I built performs an rsync command. The command fires successfully, but the line in the script that causes the command to fire throws the error `line 15: =building: command not found` when the script is fired in the terminal.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

cd ~/Desktop

mkdir -p ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/source_folder/
mkdir -p ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/target_folder/

touch ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/source_folder/file1.txt
touch ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/source_folder/file2.txt
touch ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/source_folder/file3.txt

statement="/usr/bin/rsync -avzh --progress ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/source_folder/ ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/target_folder/"
$statementResult=$($statement) # the error points to this line.
```

As I said above, when I run this script the rsync works fine. I've pulled the command out and fired it directly in the terminal and it works fine.

At first I did not have the full path to the rsync command in the script so I added it thinking that pulling the command from my path variable may be the issue but it's still throwing the error.

I've also tried putting the statement directly into the `$()` characters rather than passing it in via variable and the error still happens.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Comment: The setting of a variable in bash is --> `var=$(command)`. And then you can use the variable with `$var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the leading dollar sign.

```
statementResult=$($statement)
```

I also encourage you to store commands in functions rather than in variables.

```
statement() {
    rsync -avzh --progress ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/source_folder/ ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX/target_folder/
}

statementResult=$(statement)
```

Functions can take parameters, making it easy to invoke a pre-defined command with different arguments. When their parameters are properly quoted they can handle file names with spaces and other unusual--but permitted--characters.

For example, you could parameterize your function so it just does the `rsync` and leaves the path names up to the caller:

```
synchronize() {
    local dir=$1
    local src=$2
    local dest=$3

    rsync -avzh --progress "$dir/$src/" "$dir/$dest/"
}

result=$(synchronize ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX source_folder target_folder)
result=$(synchronize ./GGERPTTESTINGSANDBOX 'from here' 'to here')
```

Notice how this accepts directory names with spaces (`from here` and `to here`). That would be very difficult to do with a variable holding the same code.

Comment: Ah! blergh, I'm coming from a php background so my brain saw $statementResult and completely overlooked it as calling the contents of a variable rather than assigning it. Thanks! (I've got 8 mins till I can mark this as correct, I'll check it once the timer is up)

Comment: Also, what is the reasoning behind storing the command in a function rather than a variable? I'm not questioning it's validity, just want to learn.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz: the oddities of shell parsing make it hard to get a command into & out of a variable intact. See [BashFAQ 50:I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).